# Google Classroom - creates a spreadsheet for grades but doesn't automatically sync

Tags: google-sheets, google-classroom

So in Classroom I can create a spreadsheet of all my students, all the assignments, all the scores.  That's great.
However, it is a one shot deal.  New grades and assignments don't automatically sync/populate to that spreadsheet.  I am trying to create "packets" of multiple assignments and through the spreadsheet by totaling the scores of multiple assignments.  =sum() makes that part easy enough.
However, unlike using a google form, which automatically syncs and updates with new submissions, the spreadsheet created by classroom doesn't update that way.
Any tricks I can do to make any new inputted grades in classroom be automatically added to teh spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlow. Please provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When you are in an assignment and you use the tool `Copy all grades to Google Sheets` it will create an snapshot of the grades on the assignments at that moment but it will not update the values if there are any changes or new data is added (such as new assignments).

#### Workaround

To solve this and get this data dynamically into your Spreadsheet, you could make use of the [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) service for [Classroom](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/classroom) and retrieve all your desired data. This makes use of [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest) with all its functionallities. Once you get this data you could print it in your desired columns using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).