# Google Classroom grades upload automatically to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-classroom

so I made an assignment on Google Classroom. In the Classwork section, when I click on the assignment, there's a settings icon with the option to "Copy all grades to Google Sheets." Which will open a Sheets with a summary of the students' names, emails, and grades at the time that I click on it, but it won't update it with any new grades that are submitted after I click on it.

I found essentially the same question posted a while ago here ([Google Classroom - creates a spreadsheet for grades but doesn't automatically sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175981/google-classroom-creates-a-spreadsheet-for-grades-but-doesnt-automatically-sy)) but didn't see any answers. I'm not an experienced coder, but is it possible to get the Sheets to update it automatically - maybe with a script somehow?

Comment: You would need to look at the [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom) which you can access with the [Apps Script Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/classroom). Yet that would involve you learning Apps Script or another language. Though if you want simple software recommendations then you should post in https://superuser.com/ or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is quite complicated to make from scratch. Three possible alternatives:

1. When you click "Copy all grades to Google Sheets" it will open a new tab. If you quickly copy the URL before it changes to the URL of the new spreadsheet, you could make that a bookmark and it should create an updated one each time you click on it.
2. I have created [an app](https://www.lukegangler.com/resources/teacher-dashboard) that allows you to import grades but it only imports student averages.
3. [This app](https://www.gdevapps.com/app-page-gradebook) does what you want but it is not free.